# Variable not displaying in Cat Log

Tags: java, android, algorithm, variables, global-variables

I have an arraylist of Integers.  When there is a button click the data in the text field gets converted and added to the array list as an int.  Here is my code for that below

```
public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            String rate = happy.getText().toString();
            int rating = Integer.valueOf(rate);
            counter += 1;

            if (counter == 10) {
                train();
            }

            if (rating > 0 && rating < 11) {
                happyRating.add(rating);

                test = happyRating.get(0);
                Log.d("Value: ", Integer.toString(test));

            } else {

                InputAlertHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        int duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;
                        CharSequence text = "Please enter Happiness Indicator between 1 and 10";
                        Context context = getApplicationContext();
                        inputAlert = Toast
                                .makeText(context, text, duration);
                        inputAlert.show();
                    }
                });
            }
        }
```

In the function train();  I am getting data from this array list and using it in calculations.

```
public void train() {

    for (int i = 2; i < 12; i++) {

        if (happyRating.get(i - 1) < happyRating.size()){

            int x, x1, x2, y, y1, y2;
            double learningRate = -0.00002;

            x1 = happyRating.get(i - 1);
            x2 = happyRating.get(i - 2);
            y1 = iteration[i - 1];
            y2 = iteration[i - 2];

            x = x2 - x1;
            y = y2 - y1;

            if (x == 0) {
                slope = 0;
            } else {
                slope = (y2 - y1) / (x2 - x1);
            }
            j++;

            Log.d("J: ", Integer.toString(j));

            double weightAdj = happyRating.get(j) * slope * learningRate;

            weighting = (weighting + weightAdj);

            Log.d("WEIGHTING: ", Double.toString(weighting));// break;

        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }

    }
```

As I am using slope for my calculations I am getting the slope of the previous two points, so that's why I'm setting int i = 2 in my for loop.

I've put in the check to ensure I don't get an Index out of bounds exception.  My problem is, neither J nor WEIGHTING are showing up in my logcat.   Now whether this means they're not calculated or what I don't know, but they are initialised as two globals so at least that value should print?  I need to figure this out as soon as possible so if there's anyone out there that could shed some light on this, I'm sure it's something simple, but I've been looking at this project for so long my eyes hurt!!!

Thanks!

Comment: add a toast inside the else condition to check whether the if condition working..

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I can see that the code is not entering the if statement, it's going straight down to the else and breaking.  Would you have any idea why this might be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of

```
      Log.d("WEIGHTING: ", Double.toString(weighting));// break;
```

declare a keyword in logcat console, for example "output" and the write:

```
     Log.d("output","WEIGHTING: "+Double.toString(weighting));// break;
```

The first parameter of Log. must be the keyword for Your logcat output.

### EDIT

Logcat seems not to be the problem. So , the issue is at the for loop. If Your happyRating is definitely 10, following happens:

```
        for (int i = 2; i < 12; i++) {

    if (happyRating.get(i - 1) < happyRating.size()){
```

When i is reaching 11, it tries to get item nr. 10 from happyRating (because you sub 1). But there is none, maximum is item nr. 9 (because java is counting from 0). The maximum size You can reach here is 9, so You have to try another way if You need to execute the for loop for 12 times

### EDIT

Sorry, I can´t test the code for now, if there is an error, don´t downvote, I will test it when I am at home. But this should work also...

```
    public void train() {

for (int i = 0; i < happyRating.size()-1; i++) {

    if (happyRating.get(i) < happyRating.size()){

        int x, x1, x2, y, y1, y2;
        double learningRate = -0.00002;

        x1 = happyRating.get(i+1);
        x2 = happyRating.get(i);
        y1 = iteration[i+1];
        y2 = iteration[i];

        x = x2 - x1;
        y = y2 - y1;

        if (x == 0) {
            slope = 0;
        } else {
            slope = (y2 - y1) / (x2 - x1);
        }
        j++;

        Log.d("J: ", Integer.toString(j));

        double weightAdj = happyRating.get(j) * slope * learningRate;

        weighting = (weighting + weightAdj);

        Log.d("WEIGHTING: ", Double.toString(weighting));// break;

    }
    else
    {
        break;
    }

}
```

In this modification of Your code, the for loop only iterates until happyRating reaches the maximum size -2.So far I can see, You want to take with every loop the value of every first item and subtract the value of the second item from the first. The difference between this and Your code is, that You can get the last value without an exception. In Your code, when the loop reaches the maximum-1, You try to get an item of happyRating which is not existing. For example, imagine the integer "i" is at value 10. This is what Your code does:

```
        x1 = happyRating.get(i - 1);//x1 = happyRating.get(9)
        x2 = happyRating.get(i - 2);//x2 = happyRating.get(8)
        y1 = iteration[i - 1];//y1 = iteration[9]
        y2 = iteration[i - 2];//y2 = iteration[8]
```

If Your happyRating size is maximum 9, x1 wants to have a value that is not there. The size of an ArrayList (or Array) is not similar to item number. if this size is 9, the number of the last item is 8, because Java/Android counts from 0. So, You cannot get item number 9.
The for loop says, iterate as long as "i" is smaller than happyRating.size(). If happyRating.size() is 9, "i" iterates till 8 and then ends the iteration. This is what the modification of my code does, if happyRating.size() is 9:

```
         x1 = happyRating.get(i+1);//x1=happyRating.get(8)
         x2 = happyRating.get(i);//x2=happyRating.get(7)
         y1 = iteration[i+1];//y1=iteration[8]
         y2 = iteration[i];//y2=iteration[7]
```

The loop only iterates until 7, because it says -> iterate as long as i is smaller than happyRating,size()-1 (smaller than means maximum 8 --> -1 means 7).

Comment: I've tested the code adding logcat statements after each line to see where it falls down, I can see now that the code doesn't execute the if statement, excuse my ignorance but can anyone see why?  This is just my check to ensure that I don't get an index out of bounds exception

Comment: which if statement? From Your main activity or inside your train class? Could You post the logcat output?

Comment: sorry, my apologies, inside the train function.  I don't get any errors, it just doesn't execute the if, goes straight to the else and breaks.  Do I post the logcat as an answer here?

Comment: it seems that the "happyRating" doesn´t get values in Your onClick. Maybe the "rating" is 0 (or smaller) or bigger than 11. Check "rating" and make a logcat output for "rating", which value is it?

Comment: The happy rating works alright, well I certainly know the first element is added anyway as I have a log.d to test it test = happyRating.get(0);
                Log.d("Value: ", Integer.toString(test));
  So I know that the first element definitely added. So on each click it just prints the first element in the log cat.  So if I input 10, it adds it and prints in the log cat

Comment: how big is the size of "happyRating"? If You are sure you added values to it, and You are sure that You get no error like indexOutOfBoundException, than the only answer is, that  happyRating.get(i - 1) is definitely bigger than "happyRating" size. Make a logcat before Your if statement, inside your for-loop and check the value of happyRating.get(1) (because this is the first value You get).

Comment: I have changed around the code a little and at the moment, it appears to enter the if statement, however, now, I'm getting an invalid index issue, so I'm getting invalid index 9, size is 9

Comment: OK, another question. Why did You set your for-loop to 12? Because, if the size of happyRating is smaller than 12, you will get an indexOutOfBoundException. It will be better to set for (int i = 2; i < happyRating.size(); i++)

Comment: '04-22 14:04:22.484: E/AndroidRuntime(29026): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-22 14:04:22.484: E/AndroidRuntime(29026): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 9, size is 9
04-22 14:04:22.484: E/AndroidRuntime(29026):  at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:257)
04-22 14:04:22.484: E/AndroidRuntime(29026):  at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:311)
04-22 14:04:22.484: E/AndroidRuntime(29026):  at gary.sicl.project.Parent.train(Parent.java:247)'

Comment: my logic was that the weighting had to be calculated ten times and that's how many times the user is being asked for input so that's why I set the for loop for 12, happyRating.size() should be ten [0-9] so, if I put that in my for loop it will only iterate 8 times?

Comment: Thank you for all your help so far.  I know there is an issue with the for loop but I'm unsure how to rectify it.  I want to iterate through 10 times that's why i = 2 and i<12.  The reason I start at 2 is i need to get the slope.  I though that my if statement would handle that issue?  So that if happyRating.get(i - 1) was less than the array list size, carry out the calculations, however if not break

Comment: Hi, there are people down voting here but I haven't I very much appreciate your help.  The good news is when I run this there are no index errors.  However, the problem is that happyRating size seems to be 9 instead of 10, i'm not sure why, then the problem is the for loop only iterates 8 times.  Plus the weighting isn't calculating properly, it is coming out as I have set it globally, so the calcs are incorrect.  I think that is due to how you have set x1, x2, y1, y2, as these are meant to be the previous index locations of the array, are they not taking the current location and the next?

Comment: sorry my apologies, it does work and there are no errors, however, can you explain the forward slope calculation or the reason behind that rather than me just copying and pasting?

Answer (score -1):

This should work:

Log.d("J: ", "" + j);

and

Log.d("WEIGHTING: ", "" + Double.toString(weighting));